# regular expression to match string upto the last occurrence of “/”

Tags: ruby, regex

I was wondering if anyone knows how to form a regular expression that would help match utp the last occurrence of a  slashed file path like:

`fred/george/simpson/kill` should get result --> `fred/george/simpson/`

`abc/def/ghi/..v/file.jpg` should get result --> `abc/def/ghi/..v/`

Any advice would be appreciated.

THANKS FOR THE REPLIES ACTUALLY ID like to reframe the question , im not sure if I should start this as a new thread....I actually need to match everything between two '/' in a regex for example: tom/jack/sam/jill/ ---> I need to match jill

and in that case also need to match tom/jack/sam (without the last '/')

Thoughts appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably do it without regular expression. Simply find the rightmost `/` and slice it from there.

```
file = 'fred/george/simpson/kill'
last_slash = file.rindex('/')
parent_file = file[0..last_slash] if last_slash

=>fred/george/simpson/
```

Answer (score 3):

You can probably just use `File.dirname` here.

```
> File.dirname("fred/george/simpson/kill")
=> "fred/george/simpson"
> File.dirname("abc/def/ghi/..v/file.jpg")
=> "abc/def/ghi/..v"
```

You can then append a trailing slash if you need.

Comment: Im sorry I didnt mention that im using this on aws which has a flat file structure....so I cant use File methods....any more opinions? thanks

Comment: Many `File` methods (like this one) operate on strings, not on files. This will work just fine for S3.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[^\/]*$` as pattern:

```
'fred/george/simpson/kill'.sub(/[^\/]*$/, '') => "fred/george/simpson/"
'abc/def/ghi/..v/file.jpg'.sub(/[^\/]*$/, '') => "abc/def/ghi/..v/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
((?<=/).[^/]*?)$
```

And replcae matched with '' ;

Answer (score 0):

Regexs aren't for everyone. [Rob Pike warns of them with reason.](http://commandcenter.blogspot.ch/2011/08/regular-expressions-in-lexing-and.html)

```
(.*\/).*\/$
```

That being said, the above (untested!) will match what you want in capture group 1.

Let me remind you: better think long and hard why you want to use capture groups, even though you don't understand them. bsd's answer is clearly better.