# ruby regular expression match string between last two delimiters

Tags: ruby, regex

I  need to match everything between last two '/' in a regex

for example: for string tom/jack/sam/jill/ ---> I need to match jill

and in that case also need to match tom/jack/sam (without the last '/')

Thoughts appreciated!

Comment: Any particular reason you didn't just expand [your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031452/regular-expression-to-match-string-upto-the-last-occurrence-of/18031475)?

Comment: I re read your question 8 times and I still don't properly understand what you mean by *match*.

Comment: @Jeffrey : Sorry by 'match' I mean I need to extract that part of the string

Comment: @Chris : I thought itd be less confusing as a new qtn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)

```
str = "tom/jack/sam/jill/"

*the_rest, last = str.split("/")
the_rest = the_rest.join("/")

puts last, the_rest

--output:--
jill
tom/jack/sam
```

2)

```
str = "tom/jack/sam/jill/"

md = str.match %r{
    (.*)        #Any character 0 or more times(greedy), captured in group 1
    /           #followed by a forward slash
    ([^/]+)     #followed by not a forward slash, one or more times, captured in group 2
}x              #Ignore whitespace and comments in regex

puts md[2], md[1] if md

--output:--
jill
tom/jack/sam
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is given a string `tom/jack/sam/jill/` extract two groups: `jill` and `tom/jack/sam/`.
The regexp you need is: `^((?:[^\/]+\/)+)([^\/]+)\/$`.

Note that regexp does not accept `/` in the begin of string and request a `/` in the end of string.

Take a look: http://rubular.com/r/mxBYtC31N2

Comment: `If what you want is : tom/jack/sam/`. Nope.